# Generate and validate Captcha Image - Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

How to generate and validate Captcha Image, in user registration form , in Windows 8 App (metro)? I'm using XAML and C#.

Comment: What is the likelyhood for a script to hammer the registration form of your Windows 8 app? For me, using a captcha makes sense in a web scenario, but I can't really see which problem it solves in an app? To me, it only seems like it will be an obstacle for the user trying to register.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very explicit. Not quite a user registration, but rather a collection of user data to perform a business operation (calls a web service to a payment gateway system).